# Div ID uses properties from the one above it

Tags: html, rollover

The problem that i'm having is that I've specified some rollover buttons, and some div id's to control my image positions. however when i make a new div called Text and put some in, this also seems to trigger my rollover buttons? like its using code from the div above it, even though I've used the `<div>` tags:

http://jsfiddle.net/bq5MR/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example doesn't display the images.

You haven't closed your `<a>` tags which may result in the effect area being larger than you expect.

http://validator.w3.org/ - a free HTML validator which can help pinpoint invalid HTML and potential issues.

Comment: Ah! that's fixed it thanks! i was wondering what them tags did, cause i got the code off an example XD

Comment: Place a `</a>` after the content of your link

Comment: `<img>` tags can't *not* self-close. Whether you have the `/` there or not doesn't make a difference in browser rendering, and either way is technically valid HTML.

Comment: @BoltClock Updated comments and answer

Comment: @RyanConway Once your satisfied an answer has solved your problem, please select one accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing your second 'a' tag. Try closing it and see if that fixes the problem.